# Cannot run VB 2010 Windows Forms Application “without Debugging”

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Using VS2010 Ultimate SP1 (on Windows 8.1 64-bit) I’ve tried a (very) simple Windows Forms Application in VB (one form, one button, one event handler and one MessageBox.Show() call to display a message when the button was clicked). 
Built the application.
Executed this WFA with F5 (Start Debugging): it worked without any problem. 
Executed the same WFA with CTRL+F5 (Start Without Debugging) and it did not start, i.e. did not display the form. Actually it hanged and VS2010 was not responding any more [WFA_my_VB - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator) (Not responding)].

Additional details:
Used ProcExplorer and saw the following process tree (fragment):

```
devenv.exe  48-50 threads (some in Wait:Executive, most in Wait:UserRequest)
    WFA_my_VB.vshost.exe    5 threads (all in Wait:UserRequest)
    IntelliTrace.exe        8 threads (all in Wait:UserRequest)
        conhost.exe         1 thread (in Wait:UserRequest)
    WFA_my_VB.exe           1 thread (in Initialized)
    WFA_my_VB.exe           1 thread (in Initialized)
    WFA_my_VB.exe       1 thread (in Initialized)
```

Tried to force a Full (process) Memory Dump on devenv.exe: ProcExplorer did not complain, file was opened for write, but never closed!?!
Tried to force a Mini Memory dump on every WSA_my_VB.exe (subprocesses) but couldn’t: “Error writing dump file: access denied”

Tried same WFA on a different PC (Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit + VS2010 SP1) and it was executing without problems both with F5 and CTRL+F5.

Is there somewhere / something very important / basic things that I’m missing. 
TYIA

Code used:

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form1.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(104, 57)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Say Hello!"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button

End Class
```

Comment: Does your app run if you execute the EXE directly from the bin folder?

Comment: No it doesn't. It hangs as well. Thank you for asking as I forgot to mention it.

Comment: ProcExplorer is now showing:

cmd.exe    1 thread (in Wait:Executive)
 conhost.exe  2 threads (1 in Wait:UserRequest & 1 in Wait:WrUserRequest)
 WFA_my_VB.exe  1 thread (in Initialized)
 WFA_my_VB.exe  1 thread (in Initialized)
 WFA_my_VB.exe  1 thread (in Initialized)

Comment: Do you have any additional references (other than the ordinary)?

Comment: @VisualVincent No. Only: System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.DataSetExtensions, System.Deployment, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, System.XML and System.XML.Linq